# Chi-square with two degrees of freedom

Tags: probability-distributions

How to derive chi-square distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom? 
$$X=z_1^2+z_2^2 \\
f(z_1,z_2)=\frac1{2\pi} \exp\left[\frac{-1}{2}(z_1^2+z_2^2)\right]$$

Consider the transformation
$$z_1=r\cos(\theta), \qquad z_2=r\sin(\theta),$$
so that
$$X=z_1^2+z_2^2=r^2\cos^2(\theta)+r^2\sin^2(\theta)=r^2.$$
From here I don’t know how to complete.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? You know how to apply a change of variables. So presumably you know how to complete the process of finding the pdf of $(r,\theta)$.

Comment: I didn’t know how to complete to find the pdf Could you please help me with is I need to understand the process

Comment: Do you know the transformation formula that gives you the pdf directly? Do you know jacobians?